# Can two devices of the exact same make and model be detected as different using the user-agent string, or anything similar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-agent, uniqueidentifier, fingerprint

**The Scenario**

I have a situation of coding where many people will be using the same devices. Each person will have a Mac for example of the same model, and same OS.... but I still need to be able to identify them as individuals.

Is this possible to do? I'm only aware that the user-agent string is passed and am uncertain if it contains a hardware identifier or not

Comment: Well, there aren't any full matches, you could use cookies / localstorage but those could be emptied after visiting the application, or they could be denied, or they are on incognito mode, you could try IP but then people might be on the same network. I guess the question would rather be, why do you want to track them, and how precise should your tracking be, and why not use existing solutions, say google analytics for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser fingerprinting techniques like collecting not only the user agent but also other device details like available fonts, installed add-ons etc but since it violates user consent, it is perceived as illegal. Also user can intentionally change some of those to avoid detection.